# I'm trying to add extra data to my user Login. I've followed the tutorials but keep getting a Primary Key error

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, vba, authentication

I'm getting Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CLIENT'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CLIENT'. Every time I try to create a new user.  My current code, as far as I can tell mimics the tutorial [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2009/01/27/storing-user-profile-into-a-custom-table-using-createuser-wizard-control.aspx/).  My Code: 
`

```
Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles CreateUserWizard1.CreatedUser
    ' Get the UserId of the just-added user
    Dim newUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName)
    Dim newUserId As Guid = DirectCast(newUser.ProviderUserKey, Guid)

    'Get Profile Data Entered by user in CUW control

    Dim FirstName As String = DirectCast(CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FirstName"), TextBox).Text
    Dim LastName As String = DirectCast(CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LastName"), TextBox).Text
    Dim Phone As String = DirectCast(CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Phone"), TextBox).Text
    Dim Email As String = DirectCast(CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email"), TextBox).Text

    ' Insert a new record into User_Profile

    ' Get your Connection String from the web.config. MembershipConnectionString is the name I have in my web.config
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ASPNETDBConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO CLIENT(UserId, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email) VALUES(@UserId, @FirstName, @LastName, @Phone, @Email)"
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", newUserId)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email)

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConnection.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

`

Any help resolving this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `@` symbol from the `AddWithValue` method.

Comment: What is the primary key of the table CLIENT? What is the value of `newIserId` variable before the insert?

Comment: You need a new `Guid` for each new client. Your method is giving you the same `Guid`

Comment: @DonA, I changed the code to `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserId", newUserId)` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you put `@` before parameters, both ways work.

Comment: @Steve, The Primary key in CLIENT is UserId.  The value of the newUserId is a uniqueidentifier that is generated through some part of the back end code for the CreateUserWizard.

Comment: Then it seems that you get the same value for newUserId every time you click the button. It is really unlikely unless you have the same user name.

Comment: @DonA, Brilliant! That worked thanks! I'll post it as answered in 8 hours since I don't have the points to mark as answered yet.  I changed `Dim newUserId As Guid = DirectCast(newUser.ProviderUserKey, Guid)` to `Dim newUserId = Guid.NewGuid()`  Thank you for your quick responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new `Guid` for each new client. Your method is giving you the same `Guid`.